# Sencha/ ExtJS - records[x].set() not saving/ setting

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to modify a date field after reformatting the date. When I try to set the formatted date to the record, the field becomes undefined.

It seems like a straight forward procedure, but the results aren't as expected.

```
for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    var formattedDate = Ext.Date.format(records[x].data.date, 'H:i:s');
    console.log('date = ' + formattedDate); // Prints the correct formatted date
    records[x].set('date', formattedDate);
}
store.sync();

for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    console.log(records[x].data.date) // Prints 'undefined'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type is your field **date** ? If its a Date type, you must set a Date object, remember that the Ext.Date.format return a string object not a Date object.

You should try to assign a Date object:

```
myRecord.set('date',myDateObject);
```